# Which free charting library is available for UWP apps

Tags: uwp, dotnetcharting

I want to build a UWP app with gauges and some simple charts and don't want to buy a commercial product (at this stage of the project). What options are there for UWP apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **WinRTXamlToolkit** has UWP specific builds and these could be a good starting point. They don't resemble the polished commercial alternatives but it might be helpful.

These are the NuGet packages I used for chart and gauges.

- **WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.DataVisualization.UWP**
- **WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.Gauge.UWP**

This is the underlying repo: https://github.com/xyzzer/WinRTXamlToolkit

Answer (score 0):

You can use  [DataVisualisation Charting Controls](https://www.nuget.org/packages/winrtxamltoolkit.Controls.DataVisualization.UWP) from XAML Toolkit